# UWP Account Info Permission

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

```
 var user1 = await Windows.System.User.FindAllAsync(UserType.LocalUser,
             UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated);

 var user = user1.FirstOrDefault();
 var firstName = (string)await user.GetPropertyAsync(
                 KnownUserProperties.FirstName);
 var lastName = (string)await user.GetPropertyAsync(
                KnownUserProperties.LastName);
```

Package.appxmanifest has capability set:

```
    <uap:Capability Name="userAccountInformation" />
```

I have inconsistent result using the code above. I sometimes see the prompt to get permission when running the app, and sometimes I don't. I understand that it will not prompt if consent is already given, but the inconsistency is there after complete uninstall and deploy (debug) of the app. Nevertheless, it doesn't seem to toggle "Account info" setting to On for the app in Windows Settings after consent.

[image]

Running Windows 10 1903, but also remember having the issue in 1809.

Comment: Is this only for F5 debug / deploy or do you see it for a non-dev install?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I also see it for when the apps are downloaded from the store (non-dev).

Comment: Is the operation ever allowed when the user hasn't given consent, or when the toggle says "off" (when deployed from the Store)?

Comment: I'm submitting a test version to try what happens. FYI, in debug, the "Account info" toggle seems to function as intended when On/Off. My app gets the info if On, and doesn't when Off. However, when Off, my UWP app seems to just "lose it" (for the lack of a better term) after the `user.GetPropertyAsync();`. No exceptions thrown.

Comment: It behaves the same way when distributed through the Store. However, is there a way to continue gracefully if consent wasn't given? What is it that makes the consent dialog appear again? I just tried uninstalling and reinstalling and the consent dialog didn't pop up.

Comment: @CarloMendoza By my tests, I saw the different behavior with you. Every time, the prompt dialog will show there when I uninstall and reinstall the app. Please tell me the project's target version and min version. And the windows OS build version(e.g, 18362.xx).

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT running on 18362.239 I believe. Min 17632/ target 18362.

Comment: @CarloMendoza My OS build version is 18362.30. Could you please have a try?

Comment: Hmm. I don't have any machines on that version anymore.